# Using Generics and Reflections in Java for interface method implementation

Tags: java, generics, reflection, guice

I am trying to solve an exercise using Guice. I have done pretty much everything else, but this method implementation is confusing the soul out of me. The purpose of this method is to act as a registrar of loggers and there is another method which will act as a dispatch messages to the correct logger (@named loggers). I am not worried about the dispatcher too much as I know how to do that. But the registrar method MUST use generics and reflections. I am badly stuck here and my Java experience is almost non-existent when it comes to using reflections with "java.lang.Class".

The code is given below:

```
class MyManagerImpl implements MyMgr {

    /* MyListener below is an interface */
    public synchronized void regService(Class<? extends MyListener> loggerObj) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }

    public synchronized void dispatch(String msg, String logger) {
          / * dispatches the messages to the correct logger which
            * I know how to do 
            *
            */    
    }


}
```

I understand that the above wildcard-enabled type expression says "Class contains anytype that implements of, or extends, MyListener interface". But I am quite new to using Class for anonymity. Is it possible to see an example where this loggerObj is actually being modified/used to invoke a member function.

Comment: What do you mean by an "implementation body"?

Comment: Are you actually going to pass a class object, like `MyListener.class`?

Comment: You can use `listenerClass` to do lots of things in the body of `doService`. You need to clarify what the method is for.

Comment: Please elaborate, which methods are provided and which ones are you writing? Is the doService method a method of MyMgr? If so, you will need to do reflection in order to instantiate the listener inside the method which can introduce both poor performance and implicit code style. This code sample out of context is way too small to provide any useful assistance.

Comment: Hard to see what Reflection has to do with any of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make much sense I guess, what one will pass is the **Class** instance, thus to use for reflection, you **can't call** any method on it. You can perhaps do some reflection.

A better attempt would be:

```
public synchronized void doService(<? extends MyListener> listenerObj) {
    //...
    //...
    //...
}
```

but that would be rather pointless, because you can replace it by:

```
public synchronized void doService(MyListener listenerObj) {
    //...
    //...
    //...
}
```

The generics are merely used for `Collection<T>` types like:

```
public synchronized void doService(Collection<? extends MyListener> listenerObj) {
    //...
    //...
    //...
}
```

Such that you can call it with `ArrayList<SubMyListener>` or `ArrayList<SubSubMyListener>`, etc. This because the following inheritance relation **doesn't hold**:

```
ArrayList<SubSubMyListener> extends ArrayList<SubMyListener>
```

**Why is this useful?**:

Say you expect some kind of collection with `MyListener` objects, now you can provide a method with the signature:

```
Foo method (Collection<? extends MyListener> bars) {

}
```

But if one wants to call the method with a `Collection<SubMyListener>`, it doesn't follow inheritance, so the compiler won't allow it. By using wildcards, you can do this.

You can use this constraint, to **call a method defined on `MyListener`**. For instance:

```
void callAll (Collection<? extends MyListener> bars) {
    for(MyListener bar : bars) {
        bar.call();
    }
}
```

Now in the `for`-loop, Java derives an `Iterator<? extends MyListener>`. In other words, Java knows, the `Iterator` will only emit objects that inherit from `MyListener`, this can be used so that Java can perform type-checking and this is thus more safe than hoping the objects are indeed `MyListener` objects.

Comment: So you are saying that the `Class` creates more confusion?

Comment: A `Class` is more or less only used for *reflection*, that's very advanced java, where you can for instance get a list of methods of a `Class` you don't know. Even then, generics with wildcards can play a part, but it's very advanced, and using reflection, is in general not really type-safe.

Comment: Could you please recommend something on the web that I can use to solve this problem? I am not asking for holding my hands, but I really could use some materials.

Comment: @ha9u63ar: can you specify what the method *should* do, it's very unclear. Your question only seemed to ask to given an *example* on how to use it...

Comment: updated explaination - Sorry I don't want to sound I am cheating - I am simply trying to understand what is the best way implement this.